# Template Conflict between String and Int

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae, type-traits

I have a program that creates a JSON file using json-glib for ReST Server. The file has 2 field namely `id` and `value`. `id` is only `std::string` but value can be an integer, a boolean, a string (through `std::string` od `char const *`) or a floating point, depending on the value to be transmitted. I have trouble in `c.str()` function and `char *`.

```
if(std::is_integral<T>::value)
        {
            if(std::is_same<T, bool>::value)
            {
                if(json_builder_add_boolean_value (builder, tagValue) == nullptr)
                {
                    returnMessage = string("json_builder_add_boolean_value was inconsistent in setTag(Boolean). TagName : ") + tagName + string("TagValue : ") + to_string(tagValue);
    #ifdef __DEBUG
                   cerr << returnMessage;
    #endif 
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(json_builder_add_int_value (builder, tagValue) == nullptr)
                {
                    returnMessage = string("json_builder_add_int_value was inconsistent in setTag(Int). TagName : ") + tagName + string("TagValue : ") + to_string(tagValue);
    #ifdef __DEBUG
                   cerr << returnMessage;
    #endif 
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        else if(std::is_floating_point<T>::value)
        {
            if(json_builder_add_double_value (builder, tagValue) == nullptr)
            {
                returnMessage = string("json_builder_add_double_value was inconsistent in setTag(Double). TagName : ") + tagName + string("TagValue : ") + to_string(tagValue);
    #ifdef __DEBUG
               cerr << returnMessage;
    #endif 
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if(std::is_same<T, string>::value or std::is_same<T, const string>::value)
        {
            if(json_builder_add_string_value (builder, tagValue.c_str()) == nullptr)
            {
                returnMessage = string("json_builder_add_string_value was inconsistent in setTag(String). TagName : ") + tagName + string("TagValue : ") + to_string(tagValue);
    #ifdef __DEBUG
               cerr << returnMessage;
    #endif 
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if(std::is_same<T, char *>::value or std::is_same<T, const char *>::value)
        {
            if(json_builder_add_string_value (builder, tagValue) == nullptr)
            {
                returnMessage = string("json_builder_add_string_value was inconsistent in setTag(String). TagName : ") + tagName + string("TagValue : ") + to_string(tagValue);
    #ifdef __DEBUG
               cerr << returnMessage;
    #endif 
                return false;
            }


}
```

> error: request for member ‘c_str’ in ‘tagValue’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
>            if(json_builder_add_string_value (builder, tagValue.c_str()) == nullptr)
>
> error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘const gchar* {aka const char*}’ [-fpermissive]

Comment: You're looking for `if constexpr`. Plain `if` does not discard dead code.

Comment: this solution works starting from C++17 with `if constexpr`; before it, `c_str()` is compiled also when `T` is an integer; so the error

Comment: I'm using C++14. g++ 7.2 MingW and g++ 6.2 on Raspberry Pi 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using C++14

It's a pity.
You can't use `if constexpr` that is the natural solution for your problem but it's introduced from C++17.

Anyway, without `if constexpr`, the compiler must compile every part of your function; so if your `tagValue` is a `bool`, the compiler must compile also the `tagValue.c_str()` call that isn't available for a `bool`.

So the error.

Pre C++17 you have to develop different function for different types.

A possible solution is use overloading and SFINAE defining three not-template `foo()` functions for the three exact types (`bool`, `std::string const &` and `char const *`)

```
void foo (std::string const & id, bool value)
 {
   // json_builder_add_boolean_value, etc

   std::cout << "-- bool case: " << id << ", " << value << std::endl;
 }

void foo (std::string const & id, std::string const & value)
 {
   // json_builder_add_string_value, etc

   std::cout << "-- std::string case: " << id << ", " << value << std::endl;
 }

void foo (std::string const & id, char const * value)
 {
   // json_builder_add_string_value, etc

   std::cout << "-- char * case: " << id << ", " << value << std::endl;
 }
```

and two template `foo()` functions, enabled through SFINAE for integral types (the first one) and for floating point types (the second one)

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>{}>
   foo (std::string const & id, T const & value)
 {
   // json_builder_add_int_value, etc

   std::cout << "-- integral case: " << id << ", " << value << std::endl;
 }

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>{}>
   foo (std::string const & id, T const & value)
 {
   // json_builder_add_double_value, etc

   std::cout << "-- floating case: " << id << ", " << value << std::endl;
 }
```

so calling

```
   foo("1", false);
   foo("2", 0L);
   foo("3", 0.0f);
   foo("4", std::string{"zero"});
   foo("5", "zero");
```

you get

```
-- bool case: 1, 0
-- integral case: 2, 0
-- floating case: 3, 0
-- std::string case: 4, zero
-- char * case: 5, zero
```

Observe that `bool` is an integral type, so can match the `foo()` template integral version and the `foo()` `bool` specific version.

In this case is preferred the exact match, so the `bool` specific version is called.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to maintain code compatibility between Raspberry Pi application and Windows application, hence C++14 is the only option. I thought about overloading the template function but the downside is that for just one line have to duplicate all 377 lines. I am also looking at SFINAE  but it looks kind-of tricky.